# Jsoup parse HTML including span tags

Tags: java, parsing, jsoup

I have some HTML with the following format:

```html
<article class="cik" id="100">
  <a class="ci" href="/abc/1001/STUFF">
    <img alt="Micky Mouse" src="/images/1001.jpg" />
    <span class="mick vtEnabled"></span>
  </a>

  <div>
    <a href="/abc/1001/STUFF">Micky Mouse</a>
    <span class="FP">$88.00</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="SP">$49.90</span>
  </div>
</article>
```

In the above code the `<a>` tag inside article has a span `class="mick vtEnabled"` with no label. I want to check if this span tag with the class name specified is present within the article tag.

How do I do that? I tried to `select("> a[href] > span.mick vtEnabled")` and checked the size. It remains 0 for all the article tags irrespective of whether it's set or not. Any inputs?

Comment: It seems like you are asking 2 different questions, one about getting the "class" attribute values on the `<span>` tags, and the other about getting ??? [something] from the `<article>` tag. Is this correct? If so, what do you want with the `<article>` tag?

Comment: <a> and <div> tags are present inside article. I have multiple article tags. so in loops i should 1st find the article tag and then go inner and get img link from <a> tag and href link and span values from inner <div> tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from individual `article` tags would be good:

```
final String test = "<article class=\"cik\" id=\"100\"><a class=\"ci\" href=\"/abc/1001/STUFF\"><img alt=\"Micky Mouse\" src=\"/images/1001.jpg\" /></a><div><a href=\"/abc/1001/STUFF\">Micky Mouse</a><span class=\"FP\">$88.00</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class=\"SP\">$49.90</span></div></article>";
final Elements articles = Jsoup.parse(test).select("article");
for (final Element article : articles) {
    final Elements articleImages = article.select("> a[href] > img[src]");
    for (final Element image : articleImages) {
        System.out.println(image.attr("src"));
    }
    final Elements articleLinks = article.select("> div > a[href]");
    for (final Element link : articleLinks) {
        System.out.println(link.attr("href"));
        System.out.println(link.text());
    }
    final Elements articleFPSpans = article.select("> div > span.FP");
    for (final Element span : articleFPSpans) {
        System.out.println(span.text());
    }
}
    final Elements articleSPSpans = article.select("> div > span.SP");
    for (final Element span : articleSPSpans) {
        System.out.println(span.text());
    }
}
```

This prints:

```
/images/1001.jpg
/abc/1001/STUFF
Micky Mouse
$88.00
$49.90
```